# View Stretched in Storyboard iOS

Tags: xcode, ios5, uistoryboard

can anyone tell me how to get my storyboard back to normal? I'm not sure what I did but all my views seem to be stretched and I can't see the navigation bars at the top of them where I need to make changes to buttons I've put up there.

[image]

[full size screen Shot of Xcode](http://kristinareilly.com/xcodescreenshot.png)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the cause, but I had this problem a while back.

In my situation I had a TabBarController pointing to several navigation controllers. To fix the problem I just deleted the TabBarController and replaced it with a new one.

If you have no TabBarController I would try just replacing the first NavigationController where the stretching takes place and it should fix all subsequent View Controllers.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to roll back with your version control system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me what causes this? Just so I know in the future.

Comment: No idea, I've never seen it before.  If you've accidentally gone from something that works to something that doesn't, that's what version control is for, to go from something that doesn't work back to something that does.

Comment: it's almost like you went from iPhone storyboard to iPad or something. I experimented with copying and pasting storyboards from iPhone to iPad and I saw something similar happen.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me too. As Jeremy responses I had a tabBarController but I fixed by deleting the viewControllers associated to the tabBar, 1 of them was the one causing the problem, it was a Navigation controller wich I've changed the title, so the title was a little big and that did the controller to expand.